# pause embed Vimeo videos when they are out of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am building a website portfolio that is going to contain several embeded vimeo videos. To make it run faster, I was considering pausing every video which doesn't appear in the screen. I made this code from some example I found but I could only make pause the video immediately when even just a portion of it goes out of screen, I'd like to pause it only when the video is completely out of the screen. and I'd like to pause not only those who are before the viewport but also those who come after (both categories are intended like not visible anyway).

I thought that a way could be to add the player height to its top value and check if that is out of the viewport. So I've tried with the method .getVideoHeight() that I got from the [player documentation here](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/#getvideoheight-promisenumber-error) but I got an error saying that this is not a defined function.

Can you help me understand how to fix the code to achieve this?

By the way, do you think that pausing videos would actually help reduce the load of the page (it was my guess so I'm not really sure wether it's actually helpful or not)

```js
var players = []
$('.inner').each(function() {
  players.push({
    player: new Vimeo.Player($(this).find("iframe").get(0)),
    top: $(this).position().top,
    status: "paused"
  })
});
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    var elementFromTop = players[i].top - scrollPos;
    //I got an error on this log
    //console.log("this should be player " + i + " height: " + players[i].getVideoHeight());
    var status = (elementFromTop > 0 && elementFromTop < players[i].top + viewportHeight) ? "play" : "pause";
    if (players[i].status != status) {
      players[i].status = status;
      players[i].player[status]();
      console.log(i, status);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height:5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<div class="inner">
<iframe id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/10985679?autoplay=1&loop=1&color=357ded&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&muted=1&autopause=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="inner">
<iframe id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/10985679?autoplay=1&loop=1&color=357ded&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&muted=1&autopause=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="inner">
<iframe id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/10985679?autoplay=1&loop=1&color=357ded&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&muted=1&autopause=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="inner">
<iframe id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/10985679?autoplay=1&loop=1&color=357ded&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&muted=1&autopause=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to pause programatically without the scrolling logic? Because if you havent been able to pause via javascript then dont exepct to be able to pause with the additional logic.

Comment: `//I got an error on this log` ... what error did you get?

Comment: @GetSet I got this: TypeError: players[i</a>.getVideoHeight is not a function

Comment: Then perhaps you meant `players[i].player.getVideoHeight()`.

Comment: I've tried that but I get Promise as value

Comment: If the Vimeo API is returning a "promise" for that method, then thats what you need to respond to. Have you studied the API?